# On the uniqueness of a simple continued fraction

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, continued-fractions

Expanding an irrational number in form of a simple continued fraction each of the terms $a_i$ in $[a_0;a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots ]$ are 'uniquely' determined since the lowest integer less than or equal to some positive number is unique. But does the uniqueness hold in the reverse direction? That is, is it true that if both $x=[a_0;a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots ]$ and $x=[b_0;b_1, b_2, b_3, \dots ]$ then $a_i=b_i$? If so, how to prove it?

PS The same problem can happen for $x$ as a rational but if I can know the method for an irrational case so may I work on the rational case.

Comment: If zeroes are allowed then the other direction is not unique: $[\ldots, a, b, \ldots] = [\ldots, a, 0, 0, b, \ldots]$. Note that the canonical algorithm does not generate zeroes except $a_0$.

Comment: @TheVee, zeros aren't allowed considering the book's recipe. So I mean for the case that zeros aren't allowed..

Comment: OK, check my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unique in both directions, you can find the proof [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Existence_and_Uniqueness_of_Simple_Infinite_Continued_Fraction). In short, in a mathematical induction you can show that if $k$ first partial quotients agree then the $(k+1)$-th must as well, as both $a_{k+1}$ and $b_{k+1}$ are the integer parts of the same number. In other words, as $a_{k+2}$ and $b_{k+2}$ are at least 1 each, $[a_{k+1}, a_{k+2}, \ldots]$ and $[b_{k+1}, b_{k+2}, \ldots]$, for which it holds that $a_{k+1} \le [a_{k+1}, a_{k+2}, \ldots] < a_{k+1}+1$ and $b_{k+1} \le [b_{k+1}, b_{k+2}, \ldots] < b_{k+1}+1$, could never agree if $b_{k+1} \ne a_{k+1}$. The same argument, assuming $a_1, b_1 \ne 0$ (in your notation, as in the link that would be $a_2$, $b_2$), also secures the initial step of the induction.